# "new" does not call the specified constructor in a class?

Tags: c++, class, new-operator

There must be some flaws in my understandings about `new` operator.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

class MovingAverage {
public:
    /** Initialize your data structure here. */
    MovingAverage(int size) {
        queue<double> q;
        int max_size = size;
        int curr_size = 0;
        double sum = 0.0;
    }

private:
    queue<double> q;
    int curr_size;
    int max_size;
    double sum;
};

int main(){
    MovingAverage * m = new MovingAverage(3);  // This line does not work as expected!
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, the class `MovingAverage` has a constructor `MovingAverage(int size)` that sets two of its member variables `curr_size` and `sum` to zero.

However, the line `MovingAverage * m = new MovingAverage(3);` in the main function does not return a pointer to an instance of the class with the two member `curr_size` and `sum`to zero.

Instead, the debugger shows the created object has `curr_size = 1953853300` and `max_size = 6647401`.

[image]

How can I make the `new` operator calls the constructor I wrote?

Comment: You are not initializing the class member variables, but local variables in your constructor body.

Comment: `int max_size = size;` means to define a local variable called `max_size` (not to refer to some other variable of the same name)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ That solves the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @yuqli It is generally a bad practice to re-use the name of a class member into local variables or method parameters. While the compiler accepts this and the behavior is well defined, in practice it causes a lot of confusion to programmers so you’d better avoid it, plain and simple.

Comment: @vdavid Thanks for the advice. I didn't mean to declare a local variable in my question, but with this advice when I need to I'll use a different name for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is declaring local variables inside the constructor's body. The right approach is to use the constructor's [*member initializer list*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
MovingAverage(int size):
    max_size(size),
    curr_size(0),
    sum(0.0)
{}
```

Besides that, ideally you shouldn't be using raw pointers like that. There are smart pointer classes like [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) that can make the code safer and easier to maintain. So your code could be:

```
#include <memory>

...
auto m = std::make_unique<MovingAverage>(3);
```

or

```
auto m = std::make_shared<MovingAverage>(3);
```

Comment: In C++11 and later, you can initialize class members with default values right in their declarations instead of initializing them in the constructor. In the code shown, only `max_size` would need to be initialized in the constructor: `class MovingAverage { public: MovingAverage(int size) : max_size(size) {} private: queue<double> q; int curr_size = 0; int max_size = 0; double sum = 0.0; };`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the advice. I used this format in my code today :-)